# Is there a way to store all Excel VBA Google searches in a separate sheet in the Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, search, google-search

I have the code below and it works perfectly the way I want. I type a certain phrase in Excel pop-up window using VBA to search using Google Search. However, I would love to be able to store all the Excel VBA Google searches, either in the same Excel file (same/another sheet) or in another file. Does anybody know if this is possible to do? I don't know if it's the code that should be modified or the Excel settings in some way.

```
Private Const LicenseRegistration As String = "+brott+och+straff"
Private Sub CommandButtonSearch_Click()
   Dim query As String
   Dim search_string As String
   Dim googleChromePath As String
   
   query = InputBox("Enter your keyword", "Google Search")
   search_string = Replace(query, " ", "+") & LicenseRegistration
   
   googleChromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
   
   Shell (googleChromePath & " -url http://google.com/search?q=" & search_string)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AnotherSheet")
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = search_string
End With

End Sub
```

A window pops up titled "Microsoft Visual Basic" and it says: Run-time error "9":
Subscript out of range

I copied and pasted the code exactly as you wrote it, even tried to modify it a bit, but to no avail.
I really hope you can see the picture with this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1me7xBn8jGvtmpRADp5QFUFmR9k2oGzBs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Assuming by search you mean `search_string`, sure. Just write `search_string` to a separate worksheet perhaps.

Comment: @BigBen , how do you mean exactly by "write search_string to a separate worksheet"? Do I copy that part of the code and paste it somewhere else? I don't really get what you mean by what you wrote..

Comment: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AnotherSheet")`, `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = search_string`, `End With`. Write the search string to another worksheet.

Comment: @BigBen sorry again, but do you mean something like this? https://i.imgur.com/8PgzRys.png , cause it's not working (I'm probably doing something wrong)

Comment: @BigBen I've now edited my code and added the question and new link that will (hopefully) work for you.

Comment: You need to change `"AnotherSheet"` to the name of your actual sheet.

Comment: It worked! Do you want to copy and paste "With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AnotherSheet"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = search_string, End With" as an Answer so I can upvote it as the favorite answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to keep a running list of `search_string`, then you can use:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AnotherSheet") ' change sheet name as needed
   .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = search_string
End With
```

before (or even after) the `Shell` call.